# Is "hstart.exe" harmful to my computer?

Tags: windows-8, malware, malwarebytes

Today, Malwarebytes Anti-malware notified me that it had quarantined a malware, right after I logged in. It looked like this:[image]
But, when I searched the file, hstart.exe, I didn't get a definitive answer, any advice? (Windows 8.1)

Comment: You tell us.  hstart.exe appears to be the executable for [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html).  If you installed, Hidden Start yourself, then you should ignore the conclusions of Malwarebytes and notify them of the false positive.  **In my own research, the Google [results](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=hstart) I found, were very definite.**  I can't post an answer, since I have zero information on the actual file, that exists on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is malware, since I didn't install Hidden Start.

Comment: Before you jump to that conclusion.  Provide us actual information on the file.  Since the file has not yet been move, right click on it, and submit the properties of the file itself.  The developer of Hidden Start, has signed the application, so provide the `General`, `Details` and `Digital Security` property information on the actual file that exists on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the fact there is not enough information to identify, what the file your asking about, actually is I can identify the actual Hidden Start application which is likely the file your asking about..

The trial version of `Hidden Start` was created on March 14 2013.

[image]

It is signed by its developer, `Alexander Avdonin`, on March 18th 2013.

[image]

The copyright is owned by `NTWind Software`.

[image]

If the file you are asking about isn't signed then you should delete the file.  I can also confirm that `C:\Windows\hstart\hstart.exe`is not a standard directory or file, so the only reason it exists, is because you ran something that created it.